# i need to access a element from the linked list like the one i did on the normal list but cant - python

Tags: python, list, indexing, time, linked-list

What im trying to solve is ''Calculate the time to access the element stored in each randomly generated index
for both Python list and linked list. For example, n[5] is 45603. We will be
accessing the 45603. Element in both the Python list and the linked list. We know
that the Python list should immediately access the data, whereas the linked list
would take some time. Print all the accessed values to make sure that everything is
all-right'' this question

```
b = 0
c = 0
import random
import time


x = 0
N = int(input('Enter the N :'))
n = int(input('Enter the n: '))
data  = []

while x<N:
    data.append(random.randint(1, N)) 
    x = x + 1

class Node(object):
   def __init__(self, value, next=None,position = 0):
        self.value = value
        self.reference = next
        self.position = position
#convert the list to linked
class LinkedList(object):
    def __init__(self, sequence):
        self.head = Node(sequence[0])
        current = self.head
        for item in sequence[1:]:
            current.reference = Node(item)
            current = current.reference
    def listprint(self):
        printval = self.head
        while printval is not None:
            print (printval.value)
            printval = printval.reference
         
a = range(10)
datal = LinkedList(data)
current = datal.head
while current is not None:
    print(current.value)
    current = current.reference
    


for i in range(n):
    randv = random.randint(1,n)
    start1 = time.time()
    data[randv]

    end1 = time.time()

    elapsed1 = end1 - start1
    print('sample id',b,'               ','Random İndex ',randv)
    print(data[randv])
    print('Access time',elapsed1)
    
    
    
    b = b + 1
```

Comment: see [ask] a question, and how to provide a [mcve]

Comment: Welcome to SO! I don't see a question being asked here. What do you need help with?

Comment: Sorry if i didn't made it clear but i need to create a function to access the elements of the Linked list by using index number.

Comment: cant you produce a [mcve]?